# Why doesn't my example satisfy this "requires" expression?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, apply, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

I am attempting to use concepts with a variadic template. My template class is below. The concept should say: "**Each type `T` should have a member function `Func` that accepts an input of type `FuncArgType`.**"

```
#pragma once

#include <tuple>
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

template<typename FuncArgType, typename... Ts>
requires requires
(FuncArgType func_arg, std::tuple<Ts...> args) {
    std::apply([&func_arg](auto&... ts) {(ts.Func(func_arg), ...); }, args);
}
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
};
```

This appears to me to be correct, although there might be an error with my use of `std::apply`. I then try to create an object using `MyClass`. I define two classes `A` and `B` to be my `Ts`. `FuncArgType` is `int`.

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    void Func(int i) {
        std::cout << "Called Func of A";
    }

};


class B {
public:
    B() {}
    void Func(int i) {
        std::cout << "Called Func of B";
    }

};
```

I now try to create an instance of `MyClass`.

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main() {
    MyClass<int, A, B> my_class{}; // constraints not satisfied

    return 0;
}
```

The error message is

```
Source.cpp(4,19): error C7602: 'MyClass': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

(There are several other error messages, but they all essentially say that `my_class` is invalid.)

Why don't `A` and `B` satisfy my constraint? Does my constraint say what I want it to say? How do I make my constraint say the above bolded statement?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I've tried clang and gcc and the template already gives me an error without the rest.

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++20

Comment: After looking at other error messages in Godbolt, I believe that the error is with using a lambda capture in a ```requires expression```. Lambdas, ```std::apply```, and ```requires``` are still new to me, so I am still figuring it out. "error: constraint variable 'func_arg' cannot be used in an evaluated context"

Comment: Can you try `std::apply([](auto&... ts) {FuncArgType i; (ts.Func(i), ...); }, args)` ?? t=The parameter in `requires` clause is really not a variable. If okay, I'll make an answer

Comment: @nhatnq that didn't work. I am getting the following errors, which I was getting before as well "Source.cpp(4,21): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'myclass'", "'MyClass<int,A,B>': illegal use of this type as an expression", "'myclass': undeclared identifier".

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cj5an95hE

Comment: @nhatnq I copy and pasted your code exactly as written into a brand new Visual Studio project with the C++20 compiler. I got the same errors from my previous comment. I'm don't know enough about this stuff to be able to say if your code is or isn't standard-conforming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the lambda or `std::apply`. You can simply use the parameter pack directly:

```
template<typename FuncArgType, typename... Ts>
requires requires(FuncArgType func_arg, Ts... args) 
{
    (args.Func(func_arg), ...);
}
```

note that this allows implicit conversions.

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/4TfKWd1oq) is a full example.

However, your concept is correct. There was a change in C++20 that allowed capturing lambdas in unevaluated context. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079901/6205379) answer for more details on that. If you update your compiler your concept should be valid. The latest VS preview (16.11) supports this change (although intellisense shows it still as error).

Comment: It states in https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.general#nt:requires-expression. **A requires-expression may introduce local parameters**

Comment: @nhatnq the paragraph above says: _"Expressions appearing within a requirement-body are unevaluated operands."_ and lambdas used to be forbidden in unevaluated context. I couldn't find anything in the current standard regarding the lambda restriction, that's why I asked for someone to language lawyer